# Как у контрола поменять центр для его расположения?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Предположим есть контрол, который состоит из кружочка и подписи под ним. Допустим, я хочу расположить его на канве, указывая координаты *Top* и *Left*. Так вот по этим координатам будет находиться левый верхний угол контрола. А как мне **в самом контроле** указать, что по этим координатам должна быть другая точка контрола (в моем случае центр кружочка)? Если это невозможно, подскажите другой способ решения.

*RenderTransformOrigin* не подходит. Действует только при вращении.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы предолагаете размещать элемент управления только в `Canvas` и только с помощью свойств `Top` и `Left`, то можете просто задать у контрола нулевые ширину и высоту.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" x:Name="root"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Control.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="tplCircle" TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Canvas Width="0" Height="0">
                <Grid Canvas.Left="-50" Canvas.Top="-50">
                    <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </Canvas>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Control.Resources>
    <Canvas>
        <ContentControl Content="Hello" Template="{StaticResource tplCircle}"
                        Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50"/>
        <ContentControl Content="world!" Template="{StaticResource tplCircle}"
                        Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="100"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

`Canvas` внутри шаблона гарантирует выход за границы (`ClipToBounds=False`), задаёт размер (`Width=0 Height=0`), позволяет позиционировать содержимое. `Grid` содержит координаты центра (`Canvas.Left=-50 Canvas.Top=-50`) и позиционирует собственно содержимое. Во внешнем `Canvas` задаются координаты "центра" элемента.

Возможно, можно сделать проще. Экспериментируйте.

Comment: Не понял. Что мне это даст?

Comment: @iRumba Добавил пример.

Comment: Ага. Я придумал примерно то же самое, только с `Margin` в шаблоне. Пока не вижу недостатков

Comment: @iRumba Да, отрицательные отступы — это распространённый костыль CSS, в WPF тоже работает.

Comment: Из недостатков. Нельзя вычислить размер контрола, потому что он равен 0.